# Gracefully kill keep-alive connection - server side - Golang

Tags: go, gorilla

In our high throughput system we are using keep alive connections for performance.
The connections are always active and never exceed the IdleConnTimeout limit
so the connection will keep getting reused (as long as it is not broken).

This poses a problem in terms of service discovery and client-side load balancing - since address resolution only happens in the dialer's DialContext, this leaves no chance for the client to re-resolve the target address since the same connection is constantly reused without ever "re-dialing".

So, our solution is to kill keep-alive connections on the server side after a period of time.

What I tried:

Created a connection watcher, for every connection created save it in a map, with age param, after the age exceeded - kill the connection

```
type ConnectionWatcher struct {
    mu          sync.Mutex
    connections map[net.Conn]connection
}

func NewConnectionWatcher() ConnectionWatcher {
    return ConnectionWatcher{
        mu:          sync.Mutex{},
        connections: make(map[net.Conn]connection),
    }
}

type connection struct {
    conn net.Conn
}

func (this *connection) kill() {
    fmt.Println("Killing own connection")
    this.conn.Close()
}

func (this *connection) setAge(age time.Duration) {
    time.AfterFunc(age, this.kill)
}

func (this *ConnectionWatcher) OnStateChange(conn net.Conn, state http.ConnState) {
    switch state {
    case http.StateNew:
        this.mu.Lock()
        c := connection{conn: conn}
        c.setAge(10 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("Connection Created")
        this.connections[conn] = c
        this.mu.Unlock()
    case http.StateHijacked, http.StateClosed:
        fmt.Println("Connection deleted")
        this.mu.Lock()
        delete(this.connections, conn)
        this.mu.Unlock()
    }
}
```

registered this watcher to the server:

```
func main() {
    cw := NewConnectionWatcher()
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/test", ServeHTTP).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    server := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":9007",
        Handler: r,
        ConnState: cw.OnStateChange
        },
    }
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

the problem with this solution:

The connection are killed even if there are in a middle of a request handling, and then I get a lot of errors on connection closed.

I searched and try and didn't find a way to gracefully shutdown the connection

note : I am using Golang 1.18 and net/http with Gorilla/mux.

Comment: It's impossible to close keep-alived http requests gracefully: if a client decides to keep the connection open - it's now their responsibility to handle any connection related issues (including server suddenly closing it).

Comment: @zerkms I disagree, in TCP there is an option to "half close" connection, the server notify the client with fin-ack that this connection won't accept new requests and leave the outgoing open for a period of time to response current work - just did not find a way to implement in Golang

Comment: @SteveJZ: *"in TCP there is an option to "half close" connection, ther server notify the client with fin-ack that this connection won't accept new requests"* - that's not what TCP half close is. TCP half close  initiated by the server means that the server will not send any more data, not that the server will not accept any more data.

Comment: [RFC 7230 section 6.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230.html#section-6.3.1) is probably the authoritative source here. To cite: *"Connections can be closed at any time, with or without intention.
   Implementations ought to anticipate the need to recover from
   asynchronous close events. When an inbound connection is closed prematurely, a client MAY open a
   new connection and automatically retransmit an aborted sequence of
   requests if all of those requests have idempotent methods ...."*.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I remembered it's there, just couldn't find exact section, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried sending `Connection: close`? That ought to make the client close the connection after it reads the response that contains this header.